# Inner class in interface vs in class

Tags: java, nested-class, inner-classes, static-class

What is the difference between these two innerclass declarations? Also comment on advantages/disadvantages?

case A: class within a class.

```
public class Levels {   
  static public class Items {
    public String value;
    public String path;

    public String getValue() {
      return value;}
  }
}
```

and case B: class within interface.

```
public interface Levels{

  public class Items {
    public String value;
    public String path;

    public String getValue() {
      return value;}
  }
}
```

Made correction: to placement of getvalue method.

further info:
I am able to instantiate Items class in both cases A and B in another class that does not implement interface AT ALL.

```
public class Z{//NOTE: NO INTERFACE IMPLEMENTED here!!!!
 Levels.Items items = new Levels.Items();
}
```

Since an interface is not instantiated, all the elements inside an interface are accessible by dot notation without LEVELS interface instantiated simply because you cannot instantiate an interface - effectively making a class defined inside an interface permeable to static reference.

So saying that Items class in case B is not static does not make sense. Since both cases A and B are instantiated the same way, I am not looking for semantics on what is static or inner or nested. Stop giving me answers on semantics. I want the compiler, runtime and behavioural differences/advantages, or if none then say so. No more answers on semantics please!!!!! An expert on JVM or .NET VM specification innards please this answer question rather than text book semanticissiests.

Comment: I am not looking for semantics of whether it is called inner or nested class. I am looking for feature differences.

Comment: @h2g2 - after only reformatting the code - you second example is incorrect, you can't have an implemented method in an interface. Or maybe the curly brackets were not at their right places...

Comment: For the interface definition you have shown I get a compile error(both with JDK/5 and 6) "interface methods cannot have body". Did you copy/paste your code that compiles or just typed it ?

Comment: personally, i don't like public inner classes at all. if they're only used by one class i make them private, if they're used by multiple classes, they deserve their own namespace. i also would never create an inner class within an interface. i wouldn't want/expect it to work like that, but have never bothered to test.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Static inner classes are mostly similar to top-level classes, except the inner class has access to all the *static* variables and methods of the enclosing class. The enclosing class name is effectively appended to the package namespace of the inner class. By declaring a class as a static inner class, you are communicating that the class is somehow inseparably tied to the context of the enclosing class.

Non-static inner classes are less common. The main difference is that instances of a non-static inner class contain an implicit reference to an instance of the enclosing class, and as a result have access to instance variables and methods of that enclosing class instance. This leads to some odd looking instantiation idioms, for example:

```
Levels levels = new Levels(); // first need an instance of the enclosing class

// The items object contains an implicit reference to the levels object
Levels.Items items  = levels.new Items();
```

Non-static inner classes are much more intimately tied to their enclosing classes than static inner classes. They have valid uses (for example iterators are often implemented as non-static inner classes within the class of the data structure they iterate over).

It's a common mistake to declare a non-static inner class when you only really need the static inner class behaviour.

Comment: non-static inner classes are quite common, especially in graphics code

Answer (score 27):

An `static` inner class is a nested class, and the non-static is called an inner class. For more, [look here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

However, I like to quote an excerpt from the same link.

> A static nested class interacts with
>   the instance members of its outer
>   class (and other classes) just like
>   any other top-level class. In effect,
>   a static nested class is behaviorally
>   a top-level class that has been nested
>   in another top-level class for
>   packaging convenience.

You didn't use the word `static` in the second case. And you think it would implicitly be `static` because its an interface. You are right in assuming that.

You can instantiate the inner class in your interface, just like a static nested class, because its really a `static` nested class.

```
Levels.Items hello = new Levels.Items();
```

So, the above statement will be **valid in both of your cases**. Your first case is of static nested class, and in the second case you didn't specify `static`, but even then it would be an static nested class because its in the interface. **Hence, no difference other then the fact that one is nested in a class, and the other in an interface**.

Normally an inner class in a class, **not in interface**, would be instantiated like below.

```
Levels levels = new Levels();
Levels.Items items = levels.new Items();
```

**Moreover, a "non-static" inner class will have a implicit reference to its outer class. This is not the case with "static" nested class.**

Comment: Wlements in an interface are static so the second case is also a static class. Please note the question is one is enveloped by a class while the other enveloped by an interface. The question is what is the behavioral differences between embedding a static class in a class vs in an interface.

Answer (score 15):

If you declare a nested class in an interface it is always *public* and *static*. So:

```
public interface Levels{
    class Items {
        public String value;
        public String path;

        public String getValue() {return value;}
    }
}
```

Is exactly the same as

```
public interface Levels{
    public static class Items {
        public String value;
        public String path;

        public String getValue() {return value;}
    }
}
```

And even

```
public interface Levels{
    static class Items {
        public String value;
        public String path;

        public String getValue() {return value;}
    }
}
```

I've checked this with javap -verbose and they all produce

```
Compiled from "Levels.java"
public class Levels$Items extends java.lang.Object
  SourceFile: "Levels.java"
  InnerClass: 
   public #14= #3 of #23; //Items=class Levels$Items of class Levels
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  Constant pool:
const #1 = Method   #4.#21; //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
const #2 = Field    #3.#22; //  Levels$Items.value:Ljava/lang/String;
const #3 = class    #24;    //  Levels$Items
const #4 = class    #25;    //  java/lang/Object
const #5 = Asciz    value;
const #6 = Asciz    Ljava/lang/String;;
const #7 = Asciz    path;
const #8 = Asciz    <init>;
const #9 = Asciz    ()V;
const #10 = Asciz   Code;
const #11 = Asciz   LineNumberTable;
const #12 = Asciz   LocalVariableTable;
const #13 = Asciz   this;
const #14 = Asciz   Items;
const #15 = Asciz   InnerClasses;
const #16 = Asciz   LLevels$Items;;
const #17 = Asciz   getValue;
const #18 = Asciz   ()Ljava/lang/String;;
const #19 = Asciz   SourceFile;
const #20 = Asciz   Levels.java;
const #21 = NameAndType #8:#9;//  "<init>":()V
const #22 = NameAndType #5:#6;//  value:Ljava/lang/String;
const #23 = class   #26;    //  Levels
const #24 = Asciz   Levels$Items;
const #25 = Asciz   java/lang/Object;
const #26 = Asciz   Levels;

{
public java.lang.String value;

public java.lang.String path;

public Levels$Items();
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 2: 0

  LocalVariableTable: 
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      5      0    this       LLevels$Items;


public java.lang.String getValue();
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #2; //Field value:Ljava/lang/String;
   4:   areturn
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 7: 0

  LocalVariableTable: 
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      5      0    this       LLevels$Items;


}
```

Answer (score 7):

The examples you give of nested / inner classes are (IMO) bad examples.  Besides the 2nd example is not valid Java since an interface can only declare (implicitly) abstract methods. Here's a better example:

```
public interface Worker {

    public class Response {
        private final Status status;
        private final String message;
        public Response(Status status, String message) {
            this.status = status; this.message = message;
        }
        public Status getStatus() { return status; }
        public String getMessage() { return message; }
    }

    ...

    public Response doSomeOperation(...);
}
```

By embedding the Response class, we are indicating that it is a fundamental part of Worker API with no other uses.

The Map.Entry class is a well-known example of this idiom.

Comment: [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, **advantage** is that you got fewer classes cluttering your project folder if they're trivial; the **disadvantage** is that when your inner class get growing along the requirement change, the **maintenacne** become your nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the first one would declare a class Levels and a static inner class called Items. Items could be referenced by Levels.Items and would be static.

While the second would declare a simple inner class, which can be accessed by using Levels.Items, like in the following:

```
Levels.Items hello = new Levels.Items();
```

EDIT: this is totally wrong, read the comments and other replies.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a total misconception. Don't get confused with the word `static` in this case.

Comment: Moreover, your code snippet is completely valid for the `static` nested class. But not for the inner class. So, your code becomes invalid in the context you put that in. That should be something like `Levels.Items items = levelsInstance.new Items();`. Note, you can not instantiate a inner class without instantiating the outer. I hope this clears the doubt.