# static class vs singleton class

Tags: java, singleton

I know this topic has been discussed and killed over and over again, but I still had one doubt which I was hoping someone could help me with or guide me to a pre-existing post on SO.

In traditional C, static variables are stored in data segments and local variables are stored in the stack. Which I would assume will make static variables more expensive to store and maintain when compared to local variables. Right?

When trying to understand in terms of Java or C#, would this be dis-advantage for static classes when compared to singleton class? Since the entire class is loaded into memory before class initialization, I don't see how it can be an advantage unless we have small inline-able functions.

I love Singleton classes, and would hate to see it become an anti-pattern, I am still looking for all the advantages that come with it...and then loose to the argument of thread-safety among others.

-Ivar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different from C, the `static` keyword in Java class definition merely means, *This is just a normal class like any other class, but it just happens to be declared inside another class to organize the code*. In other words, there is no behavioral difference whatsoever between the following 2 way of declaration*:
a)

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    static class Me {
        // If you "upgrade" me to a top-level class....
    }
}
```

b)

```
class Me {
    // I won't behave any different....
}
```

Class definitions are loaded to memory when the class is used for the first time, and this is true for both "static" and "non-static" classes. There are no difference in how memory will be used, either. In older JVMs, objects were always stored in heap. Modern JVMs *do* allocate objects on stack when that is possible and beneficial, but this optimization is transparent to the coder (it is not possible to influence this behavior via code), and use of the `static` keyword does not have any effect on this behavior.

**Now, back to your original question, as we have seen we really can't compare static classes and Singleton in Java as they are completely different concept in Java** (I'm also not sure how static classes would compare with Singleton, but I will focus on Java in this answer). The `static` keyword in Java is overloaded and has many meanings, so it can be confusing.

**Is `Singleton` automatically an "anti-pattern"? I don't think so. *Abuse* of Singleton is, but the Singleton pattern itself can have many good uses. It just happens to be abused a lot. If you have legitimate reason to use the Singleton pattern, there is nothing wrong in using it.**

---

*Note: Why write `static` at all, you might ask. It turns out "non-static" nested classes have their own somewhat complicated memory management implication, and its use is generally discouraged unless you have a good reason (pls refer to other questions for more info).

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    Stuff stuff;
    class Me {
        void method(){
            // I can access the instance variables of the outer instance 
            // like this:
            System.out.println(SomeOtherClass.this.stuff);
            // Just avoid using a non-static nested class unless you 
            // understand what its use is!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Singleton class is essentially a regular top-level class with a `private` constructor, to guarantee its singleness. Singleton class itself provides a way to grab its instance. Singleton classes are not very easy to test, therefore we tend to stick with the idea of [Just Create Once](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne).

`static` class is essentially a nested class. A nested class is essentially a outer level class which is nested in another class just for packaging convenience. A top-level class can not be declared as `static`, in Java at least -- you should try it yourself.

> would this be dis-advantage for static
>   classes when compared to singleton
>   class?

Your this question became somewhat invalid now, according to the above explanation. Furthermore, a `static` class (of course nested) can also be a singleton.

**Further reading:**

- [Inner class in interface vs in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845731/inner-class-in-interface-vs-in-class/1845768#1845768)

Answer (score 0):

The differences between one and the other is the memory management, if your app will have to instantiate a lot of things, that will burn the memory like a charm becoming a memory problem,  performance and other things...
this could help...

http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne
http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/SingletonAndMonostate.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is an anti-pattern:
http://thetechcandy.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/singletons-is-anti-pattern/

Comment: This is in fact a great article, it talks about both the problems with single and when and how to use it if  you so choose to. I don't understand why anyone would give it a down vote.