# How I can access ineer class method in abstract class all are in interface?

Tags: java

```
 interface Hello {
   abstract class A {
     void show() {
       B b = new B();
       b.dis();
     }
    }
    class B {
      void dis() {
        System.out.println("HIiiiiiiii");
      }
    }
 }
```

But this is not working please any one guide me how I can access this because this requirement should not be changed..

Comment: You're gonna have to be way more clear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you want the following:

```
new Hello.B().dis();
new Hello.A(){}.show();
```

where `new Hello.A(){}` instantiates an [anonymous](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue002.html) subclass of the abstract class `A`.

**Edit**

If `B` is defined inside `A`, then you'd want:

```
(new Hello.A(){}.new B()).dis();
new Hello.A(){}.show();
```

Where the `dis()` call looks the way it does because `B` will no longer be an implicitly static inner class, so it will need an instance of `A`.

Comment: Dear Hello is interface How You can instantiat

Comment: There's no need to define and instantiate a class implementing `Hello`. We just take the interface class name to access the inner classes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1845893/105224

Comment: sorry for my question actually B class is inside abstract class means inner class of abtract class