# Inner Class inside an Interface implementing same Interface, what we are achieving by this?

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

## My Question:

I was looking at the source code of TextWatcher and I didn't get the concept here. 
What was the point of extending to NoCopySpan?

## TextWatcher.java:

```java
public interface TextWatcher extends NoCopySpan {
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after);
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count);
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s);
}
```

## NoCopySpan.java:

```java
package android.text;

/**
 * This interface should be added to a span object that should not be copied into a new Spanned when performing a slice or copy operation on the original Spanned it was placed in.
 */
public interface NoCopySpan {
    /**
     * Convenience equivalent for when you would just want a new Object() for
     * a span but want it to be no-copy.  Use this instead.
     */
    public class Concrete implements NoCopySpan {}
}
```

Comment: I think is just a ```helper``` class that should be used when you need to pass    an instance of  ```NoCopySpan```.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NoCopySpan` is just a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern). According to javadoc it is used to modify behavior of copy routine of `Spanned` objects (it relies on type of components). For example [`android.text.SpannableStringBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java#75) uses such inheritance information to skip spans copying upon construction.

This approach has some drawbacks but still pretty common. The reason of `Concrete` class existence is to provide convenient way to construct on-op dummy (or default) realization of `NoCopySpan` interface.

Comment: Any reference or explanation for : "modify behavior of copy routine of Spanned objects" AND "provide convenient way to construct on-op dummy (or default) realization of NoCopySpan interface".

Comment: @HishamMuneer I'm not an android expert but there is an examples you can find in android source code i.e [android.text.SpannableStringBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java#75). I'll modify my answer

Comment: @HishamMuneer hm... I can't find examples for recent 5.1.1 android. It seems that `NoCopySpan` is still used for backward compatibility or soon may be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend. Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As for the specification of the interface `NoCopyScan`, the inner class implementing the same interface can be used as a **default implementation/representation** of the interface anywhere outside.

An [inner class in an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1845768/6159397) is treated as a static inner class implicitly. We can instantiate the interface's inner class just like a static inner class and put `NoCopyScan` to use. Please find a simple example depicting the usage of default implementation of the interface with the help of the inner class below:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
interface NoCopy{

public void doStuff();

public class Conc {             //Inner Class
    public int retStuff(){
        return 2;
    }
    }




//  public void doStuff(){
//      System.out.println("Overriding in inner class");
//  }
}


 class ConcOut {

    public int returnStuff(){
        return 5;
    }


    public void doStuff(){
        NoCopy.Conc innerObj = new NoCopy.Conc();    //Instantiating inner class
        //NoCopy.Conc innerObj = (new ConcOut()).new Conc();

        System.out.println("overriding in outside class ConcOut "+ innerObj.retStuff());                              // calling the method of inner class
    }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        ConcOut conObj = new ConcOut();
        conObj.doStuff();
        //ConcOut.Conc concInner = conObj.new Conc();

    }
}
```